# create GIF image with fixed colormap using Image Magick

Tags: imagemagick, quantization, color-mapping

I want to save .gif conversions of other images with a specified colormap. The "-remap cmap.gif" option in Image Magick

example:  convert -remap cmap.gif input.png output.gif

DOES process input.png using the specified colors from cmap.gif, but it changes the order in the output colormap. Is there a way to force Image Magick to used EXACTLY the same colormap?

I am attempting to add new images to an ancient display program that accepts .gif file input but uses a fixed colormap with no ability to alter the colormap for individual images.

Comment: If you are using version 6+ your input image is in the wrong place but this may not effect the outcome convert input.png -remap cmap.gif output.gif

Comment: I'm using Q8, but the order doesn't make any difference in this case. I'm actually using label to create an image of some text and I need the color to correspond to the same index used in cmap.gif. The example was just a simplified command that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Does it help to add the `+dither` parameter?

```
convert  input.png  -remap cmap.gif  +dither  output.gif
```